# Checking the entered matrix for correctness

Tags: f#

Good day! I has written a function for sparse binary matrices input, but don't know how to check it for correctnes (number of elements in every row must be equal). Thanks!

```
  let readMatrix file =
        let processLine (str: string) (i, lst) =
            str.Split ' '
            |> Array.fold (
                           fun (j, lst) c ->
                               if c = "1"
                               then (j + 1, I(i * 1<_rows>, j * 1<_column>) :: lst)
                               elif c = "0"
                               then (j + 1, lst)
                               else failwith "Matrix has incorrect format")
                            (0, lst)
    
        let mtx =
            System.IO.File.ReadAllLines file
            |> Array.fold (fun (i, lst) str -> (i + 1, processLine str (i, snd lst))) (0, (0, []))
            |> snd
    
        mtx
```

Comment: Like I already told you on Russian SO, the concept of "correctness", as you define it, doesn't make sense. Since you're only recording ones, but not zeroes, you can treat the matrix as being infinite, with zeroes at infinity to the right and towards the bottom.

Comment: Where is the code failing? With what error?

Comment: @Nostradamnit this code isn't failing, but i want to check input data somehow. There is already one check in my code (binary matrix mustn't have anything except 0 and 1). Commentator above didn't understand me properly, i need to check data from file anyway, because non-existent symbol ≠ 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Background**: in our conversation [on Russian SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1207549/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) you have explained that, while the resulting matrix is "sparse" (i.e. encoded as a list of all coordinates of ones, zeroes omitted), and the notion of correctness indeed doesn't make sense for it, that's not what you'd like to check. What you actually wanted to check is the correctness of the *input* - i.e. that all lines of the input are indeed of the same length.

**For a minimal-diff fix**, you can just take the result of `ReadAllLines` and check if they all have the same length, before even starting to process them. The quick-n-dirty way to do that is to just take the length of each line and then dedupe them (i.e. take distinct ones) and see if you got more than one result:

```
let lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines file
let distinctLengths = lines |> Array.map String.length |> Array.distinct
if distinctLengths.Length > 1 then failwith "Rows have different sizes"

let mtx =
    lines
    |> Array.fold (fun (i, lst) str -> i + 1, processLine str (i, snd lst)) (0, (0, []))
    |> snd
```

**Separately, I would recommend a cleaner approach to computation in the first place**. `fold` is, of course, all-powerful, but with great power comes huge electricity bill. It's kind of cumbersome to understand what the program even does, which is probably why you have difficulty with adding a feature to it.

What you really want to do is (1) number the rows, (2) number the columns, (3) throw away all zeroes, (4) glue all the results in a single list.

This can be very comfortably done with a list comprehension:

```
let readMatrix2 file = 
  let lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines file
  let distinctLengths = lines |> Array.map String.length |> Array.distinct
  if distinctLengths.Length > 1 then failwith "Rows have different sizes"

  [ for row, line in Seq.indexed lines do
      for col, cell in Seq.indexed(line.Split(' ')) do
        if cell = "1" then yield I(row * 1<_row>, col * 1<_column>)
        elif cell <> "0" then failwith "Matrix has incorrect format"
  ]
```